# Gmail App Expanded Email Notification Not Collapsed Automatically

Tags: notifications, gmail

Recently I freshly installed the Gmail app from the Play Store and it had this nice feature which offered a peek of my email in the notification area whenever I swiped down the notification tray; it also had the reply/delete buttons.

But now all of a sudden that feature is literally gone. Now, whenever I receive an email I do get the notification but in kind of that classic way and to have a preview of my email and the reply/delete buttons to appear I have to slide down that notification (either by dragging it by one finger or tap-holding that notif. and then dragging it down as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3038600?hl=en) on Google's Help Page) a bit every single time which is kinda annoying.

I have Android 4.2.1 installed on my phone. And have checked all related settings to no avail :|

Please help :(

Comment: I think it automatically expands if it is the last notification... (or the "next on the list" when you dismiss one)

Comment: @Shywim Thanks for replying. It is already the last notification (the first one being my Web Root Antivirus; which is a permanent notification). But in my case it doesn't automatically expands like it was earlier :3

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behaviour, however I think it may have been different in older versions of Android/different ROM's.

On all the apps on my device that use expanded notifications, only one seems to be expanded by default. There is (most likely) an option for developers to make it expanded by default, and this may have been recently disabled in the gmail application.

As this is done at a program level, there would be no way to change it.